# Chrome and Firefox cannot evaluate XPath on SVG <foreignObject> element

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, xpath

Sample SVG:

```
<svg width="100%" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150">
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <title>title</title>
      </head>
    </html>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Returns `null` when the script below is executed within the console:

```js
document.evaluate("/svg/foreignObject/html", document,
    null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext()
```

Is there anything wrong in the XPath or the `document.evaluate()` call?

Answer (score 1):

Your XML has 2 default namespaces defined at different element level. You can read about handling namespaces when using `document.evaluate()` in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_User_Defined_Namespace_Resolver). Basically, you need to define a prefix to default namespaces URI mapping as a namespaces resolver function:

```js
function nsResolver(prefix) {
  var ns = {
    'xhtml' : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    'svg': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  };
  return ns[prefix] || null;
}
```

Use the above prefix to reference element in corresponding namespaces in your XPath and pass the namespace resolver along with the XPath:

```js
document.evaluate("/svg:svg/svg:foreignObject/xhtml:html", 
                    document, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
```